# Is it possible to make a pymysql connection to a MySQL docker container?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pymysql, docker-for-mac

I am having trouble making a connection to a MySQL container using pymysql from outside a container on Mac OSX, though I am able to connect to the docker MySQL with MySQL Workbench.

I used the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 6603:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

And the following pymysql

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    port=6603,
    user='testuser',
    password='password',
    charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
```

And received the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'testuser'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: NO)")
```

The same applies when trying to login as root.

I have tried:
1) Granting privileges in many permutations, also setting up HOST as '%'
2) Removing and recreating the mounted volume

Mainly I want to be able to access the MySQL database from an interactive shell during development.

Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you didn't provide a password when trying to connect from Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the IP address 127.0.0.1, or localhost, or your external IP address instead of 0.0.0.0. The address 0.0.0.0 is a [special IP address](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) that only makes sense when creating a listening socket, but it makes no sense for creating a connecting socket.

Comment: And how did he get the response from the server? Try `0.0.0.0` on a service that listens on it and be surprised!

Comment: I have no problem connecting to the Docker container via MySQL Workbench with 0.0.0.0:6603, whether it is root or testuser, so it seems this is probably the correct information